# how to produce a dired buffer listing all untracked files?

Tags: dired, git

`git status` tells me names of files that are currently untracked.  How can I get a dired buffer containing those files? e.g. if I run the command `git ls-files --others --exclude-standard`, I'd like all of those files in a dired buffer?

Something like `M-x find-dired` would work, except I don't want the output of find, I need the output of the git command above.

Comment: If you want such feature, why don't you give Project/Helm Projectile a try? It uses Ido or Helm to give you the file list and you can interactive filter the list. With Helm, you can do things like copy/move/delete the files.

Comment: Why do you need it? What do you want to do with the files?

Comment: I am not aware of Helm etc yet.  Looks like I have a lot to catch up on.

Comment: 'Why do you need it?'  Once I have the buffer list, I'd like to then delete most (but not all) of them after quickly browsing their contents.  dired is natural to me for this kind of op.

Comment: @StephenEglen You can check [my Helm guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html) and [my Helm Projectile guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-projectile.html) to learn both Helm and Helm Projectile. They are very useful if you work on VCS projects. If there's none, simply creating an empty `.projectile` file and Projectile will treat the directory that has that file as project root and use `find` to retrieve the file list.

Comment: @StephenEglen Oh I didn't read your requirement carefully. If this is what you want, simply use [magit](https://github.com/magit/magit) and run `magit-status`. It will give you a list of untracked files and you can jump on it with `RET`. [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Magit) has a short tutorial on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
(defun my/dired-untracked (dir)
  (interactive "DUntracked in directory: ")
  (cd dir)
  (switch-to-buffer (get-buffer-create "*untracked*"))
  (shell-command "git ls-files --others --exclude-standard | xargs ls -l" (current-buffer))
  (dired-mode dir)
  (set (make-local-variable 'dired-subdir-alist)
       (list (cons default-directory (point-min-marker)))))
```

It prompts for a directory, changes to the directory, runs the git command, and finally turns this into an actual `dired` buffer.

If you are using `magit`, however, it is much nicer to see all tracked and untracked files in the buffer created by `magit-status`.  It doesn't behave like a `dired` buffer but you can visit and delete files from there as well.

Comment: You should `cd` after you switch buffer, else you mess up the default-directory of the current buffer.

Comment: Nice ! It could be improved by showing folders instead of flattening them.